# request.getAttribute() is not showing correct output in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am sending html string from servlet to jsp page via `request.setAttribute` but when I try to get it on `jsp` it doesn't show correctly in view.

servlet:

```
String sampleHtml = ""
    + "<table class=\"table table-bordered\">"
        + "<thead>"
                + "<tr>"
                    + "<td>Data</td>"
                    + "<td>More Data</td>"
                + "</tr>"
        + "</thead>"
        + "<tbody>"
            + "<tr>"
                + "<td>Macdonal</td>"
                + "<td>David</td>"
            + "</tr>"
        + "</tbody>"
    + "</table>";           
}

request.setAttribute("userRoles", sampleHtml);
```

jsp:

```
<p>
    <label>Set Roles</label>
    <span class="field">
        <%=request.getAttribute("userRoles") %>
    </span>
</p>
```

when I reload my view result becomes totally wrong. Table goes outside of `span` tag. I have attached picture to give clear idea that what is wrong!
[image]

Comment: Please, check the output in the source. The elements panel does some fixes to broken HTML code, so you won't see the original code. In that case, Chrome might be telling you that `table` inside `span` is not allowed, or there is some other broken html in the page. Check the source (CTRL+U). In fact, if you try to validate your page, you'll see that `table` is not allowed inside `span`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span is an inline element by default. It cannot contain block elements in it. Hence you cannot add a table to it. Consider changing span to div.

From [`span docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

> The HTML  element is a generic inline container for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything.

And please do not write HTML in servlets. Use JSTL or JS.

Comment: This works & Specially Thanks for *`span docs`* + suggestions of using JSTL and JS

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to send HTML code to view from cotroller. Prepare data in your controller and send it to your view, for example:

```
request.setAttribute("userRoles", roles);
```

And then in jsp draw table using html and jstl foreach:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>More Data</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <c:forEach items="userRoles" var="role">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${role.data}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${role.moreData}"/></td>
        </td> 
     </c:foreach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And don't forget to add to your jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

And add to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

It is more flexible way, because your processing logic and view preparation are decoupled, you can replace table to list (for example), add styling without any controller logic changes

Answer (score 0):

put it on a `div` tag

```
<div class="field">
    <%=request.getAttribute("userRoles") %>
</div>
```